# android webview overlaying toolbar

Tags: android, webview, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I have started a new Android project using the Navigation Drawer template provided by Android Studio. This comes with a Side NavigationView activity and a standard Toolbar activity by default. I have attempted to add a WebView activity but for some reason, it seems to overlay the Toolbar. The space where the Toolbar would be, is still visible as a rectangle at the top of the page but the Menu buttons and Title are no longer visible. There have been a number of similar questions already asked but none appear to address this particular presentation exactly. I have attached code below for app_bar_main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView_Dash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and for **MainActivity.java**

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView_Dash);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.nz/?gws_rd=ssl");
```

If I don't load a URL, the Toolbar displays normally. As soon as I call loadUrl the contents of the Toolbar to disappear. I would appreciate any advice which could help rectify this. I'm pretty new to android dev so keep it simple, please :)

Comment: Just place your "WebView" inside the scrollView.so scrollView becomes parent of your webview enabled scrolling under the Toolbar

Answer (score 3):

You should ensure the `WebView` is *below* the `Toolbar`:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/WebView_Dash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` should help since it would offset the content below the `Toolbar`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your post. Yes I have tried this and the WebView placement appears to be fine but the Toolbar is still blank eg. no Menu button or Title

Comment: Well that's another issue from "overlaying Toolbar". You probably did not setup your `Toolbar` correctly. Without it's Java code I cannot help more. I recommend you open another question about that "blank Toolbar" ;)

Comment: That's the frustrating part. If the WebView is removed, the Toolbar buttons & title display perfectly. If the WebView is put back in, the Toolbar goes blank. So the two are linked somehow. I didn't setup the Toolbar code, as mentioned earlier it came with one of the standard Templates in Android Studio. Am I expecting too much that this should already be setup correctly..?

Answer (score 1):

just add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your webView it will come right below toolbar.

Comment: Hi thanks for your post. Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work either. Toolbar is visible as a rectangle at the top of the screen but blank - no Menu button or Title